# Using uncount to duplicate some columns but not others in r

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset that has two different counts, and the end goal is to get the ratio of one to the other for a given year. Each row is the same group of people - so in the dataframe below, the first observation was a group of people in 1990 with 9 total members, one of whom has a certain characteristic of interest.

```
year <- c(1990, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1992)
count_1 <- c(9, 8, 8, 7, 4)
count_2 <- 1, 0, 0 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(year, count_1, count_2)
```

In order to plot this, it appears that I need one row for each individual, rather than the group count. I can achieve this with `uncount()` below:

```
df <- df %>%
uncount(count_1, .remove = F)
```

This works perfectly for the `count_1` column - the total observations is 36 which matches the total number of people. However, it also repeats the `count_2` column, so now instead of 3 total people with the characteristic of interest we have 20. Is there a better way to expand the dataset, or maybe a better way to structure the original data to make this work?

I've tried `expandRows()` as well and encounter the same problem. I've also tried pulling `count_2` out of the dataframe first to preserve it, but now I'm not sure how to put it back into the final dataframe and match the observations since the row numbers are different now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not super clear (why use `uncount`?), so I am giving you two approaches based *only* on this sentence:

> the end goal is to get the ratio of one to the other for a given year.

```r
year <- c(1990, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1992)
count_1 <- c(9, 8, 8, 7, 4)
count_2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
dat <- data.frame(year, count_1, count_2)
```

Using the `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
  mutate(ratio_2_to_1 = count_2 / count_1)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>    year count_1 count_2 ratio_2_to_1
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1  1990      17       1       0.0588
#> 2  1991       8       0       0     
#> 3  1992      11       2       0.182
```

Using the `data.table` package:

```r
library(data.table)

data.table(dat)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="year"][
                , ratio_2_to_1 := count_2 / count_1][]
#>    year count_1 count_2 ratio_2_to_1
#> 1: 1990      17       1   0.05882353
#> 2: 1991       8       0   0.00000000
#> 3: 1992      11       2   0.18181818
```

Comment: Thanks, but this basically has the same problem as I originally had - there are still 9 observations in 1990 where `count_2` is 1, when I'm hoping for there to only be 1 observation.

Comment: Thank you, this absolutely works to get the ratios I was looking for!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you. Otherwise, you can just wait for more responses.